# Laravel query builder - Raw statements

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, query-builder

Struggling to get my head around raw statements I have the following:

```
        $f = DB::table('Likes')
            ->join('Freestyle', 'Likes.FreestyleID', '=', 'Freestyle.id')
            ->join('User', 'Freestyle.ParticipantId', '=', 'User.id')
            ->join('Beat', 'Freestyle.BeatId', '=', 'Beat.id')
            ->join('Track', 'Beat.TrackId', '=', 'Track.id')
            ->join('Genre', 'Track.GenreId', '=', 'Genre.id')
            ->select('Likes.*', 'Freestyle.*', 'Beat.TrackId as UseMeForTrack', 'Genre.id as GenreID', 'Track.Title as TrackTitle', 'User.slug', 'User.Username')
            ->addSelect(DB::raw('COUNT(Likes.FreestyleID) as freestyle_likes'))
            ->whereNull('Likes.deleted_at')
            ->groupBy('Freestyle.id')
            ->where('Freestyle.Active', '1')
            ->where('Freestyle.created_at', '>', "$dateScope")
            ->whereNull('Freestyle.deleted_at')
            ->whereIn('GenreID', $request->genres)
            ->get();
```

And this returns a count of the amount of likes my freestyle has as well as all of the information / filters. It's working great.

I need to do a check to see if my `Auth::id();` exists inside of the `Likes.UserId` column where the `Likes.FreestyleID = Freestyle.id`. Essentially I'm checking whether or not the user likes the freestyle so I can update my front end. Is this something I can achieve with `DB::raw`?